# Understanding an estimate

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, estimation

I am trying to understand an estimate from the post: [Lower bound for expectation of maximum absolute value of standard normal random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4165816/lower-bound-for-expectation-of-maximum-absolute-value-of-standard-normal-random). In particular, in the answer posted there, we used the following fact:
$$
\left( 1 - \frac{c}{n^{u^2}} \right)^n \leq \alpha^{1/u^2}
$$
for some $\alpha \in (0, 1)$ only depend on $c$ and not $n$ or $u$. Here $c$ is an absolute constant that is potentially greater than 1, $u$ may be assumed to be large and $n \geq 2$. However, I have failed to see why this is true. Perhaps we can rewrite this as $e$ to the power of something, but I do not see how.